# how setup mail domain (MX, SRV,TXT) in Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: email, google-cloud-dns

I just purchased mail domain service to my new domain. 
Domain was registered in GoDaddy, mail domain purchased also in goDaddy( looks like outlook365)
But Nameservers are  routed to Google nameservers, because hosting is in Google Cloud

I already did all setup in Google DNS Cloud yesterday, but still unable to continue to complete email setup in GoDaddy portal.

```
Before we can finish setting up your account, we need to verify that you own domain>
Sorry, we can't verify your settings, yet. It can take up to 24 hours for us to detect the update. Please double-check you entered the information correctly, and try again in a bit.
```

Here are my screenshots from GCP DNS
So I am not sure if I did correctly all settings in Cloud DNS.
Can you plese check my conf in GCP DNS ?
Specially I am not sure if I've filled correctly SRV, TXT data fields,

So I receive this conf info from Godaddy : how to setup >

1)

TXT Record: Find where to add a TXT record and enter

```
Name    TXT Value
@   MS=ms5789897
@   v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

2)
CNAME Records: Find  where to add a CNAME record and enter

```
Host    Points to
autodiscover    autodiscover.outlook.com
sip sipdir.online.lync.com
lyncdiscover    webdir.online.lync.com
email   email.secureserver.net
msoid   clientconfig.microsoftonline-p.net
```

3)
MX Records: Find where to add an MX record and enter

```
Host    Priority    Target
@   0   mydomain.mail.protection.outlook.com
```

4)

SRV Records: Find where to add an SRV record and enter

```
Port    Protocol    Name    Service Priority    Weight  Target
443 _tls    @   _sip    100 1   sipdir.online.lync.com
5061    _tcp    @   _sipfederationtls   100 1   sipfed.online.lync.com
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. You might have better help on [su] for example, but only after doing a search to see if your question is not there yet. Also the help section/forums/support of your provider should be a first stop too. Aside, make sure not to use `mydomain` when you want to obfuscate things. Obfuscating will make troubleshooting more difficult and hence the replies will be more difficult/less relevant to your case, and if you absolutely need to do it, please use `example.com` or `example` reserved TLD (see RFC 2606 for all details).

Comment: OK, I removed DNS tag, ...yes I already did research on web, but not found exactly resolution for my case, also support in goDaddy have no exact howtos for GCP, and Google have no support except billing in GCP

Comment: The problem is not the tag. Your question is NOT about programming. This forum is about programming questions, see [tour] and [help]. You are paying two providers and none of them has any help/support relevant to you?

Comment: godaddy has only standard howtos for all providers, not specific, and GCP is support only for premium users

Comment: So maybe they are not a good fit for your needs. Anyway, look at other forums like [su] or even [webmasters.se] and do searches there, it would be most improbable that you are the first one in your specific case so others should have discussed it already. Also you are using a specific third provider for your emails, did you ask it for help on how to set your DNS records?

Comment: I am sorry, mydomain.com was only example

Comment: Yes but do not use it as an example. It exists for real. So using it as an example can cause disruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally mail setup is done.  :)
Issue was TXT verification, I got multiple TXT records in DNS before...FIxed, so feel free to remove this topic :)